# Need help to resolve PHP Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php, class

I am using a function as follows in my class file user.php.  The create function is to add an entry to any table.

```
    public function create ($table, $fields = array()){
    $columns = implode(',',array_keys($fields));
    $values = ':'.implode(', :', array_keys($fields) );
    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$columns}) VALUES ({$values})";
    if ($stmt = $this -> pdo -> prepare ($sql)){
    foreach ($fields as $key => $data) {
    $stmt-> bindValue (':' .$key, $data);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    return $this ->pdo->lastInsertId();
    }
```

I am getting the following error

```
    PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid 
    parameter number: parameter was not defined in \core\classes\user.php on 
    line 93
```

Line 93 is $stmt->execute();

Following array is passed to the Create method as part of a registration form:

```
    } else { $user_id = $getFromU -> create('users', array('email' => 
    $email,'password'=>md5($password), 'screenName' => $screenName, 
    'profileImage' => 'assets/images/defaultProfileImage.png' , 
    'profileCover '=>'assets/images/defaultCover.png')); $_SESSION 
    ['user_id'] = $user_id; header('Location: includes/signup.php?step=1'); }
```

Please help me to identify the issue.

Comment: Show us the array what your passing to the method. Why are you putting whitespace between your `->`'s

Comment: Array passed to the method as below :                                                                                } else {
   $user_id = $getFromU -> create('users', array('email' => $email,'password'=>md5($password), 'screenName' => $screenName, 'profileImage' => 'assets/images/defaultProfileImage.png' , 'profileCover '=>'assets/images/defaultCover.png'));
   $_SESSION ['user_id'] = $user_id;
   header('Location: includes/signup.php?step=1');
    }

Comment: Add it to your question (formatted).

Comment: The given code would work fine https://3v4l.org/h6Og6.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  - thanks for validating. Not sure why it does not work in the actual script.